# Batch What is the best way to add a script to the startup

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, clearcase

I have some script that is written in `batch` it is uninstalling Rational Softwares (ClearCase, ClearQuest), i'm adding another script to the startup, but somehow while the script is running this registry key is being removed.
Here is my script:

```
SET ratinalDestFolder=C:\Rational_SW

SET UninstallTool=\\ta1bbn01\Public\Migration\CC\rationaluninstalltool.exe
::SET logFile=\\ta1bbn01\Public\Migration\uninstallLogs\%COMPUTERNAME%-%USERNAME%.log
SET logFile=%ratinalDestFolder%\%COMPUTERNAME%-%USERNAME%.log

ECHO Adding the registry file of the installation script
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v RATIONAL_INSTALLATION /d \\ta1bbn01\Public\Migration\Alex\rationalInstallationWin64_Final.bat || ECHO Failed to add isntallation script

ECHO Copying the uninstall tool %ratinalDestFolder%
xcopy   %UninstallTool% %ratinalDestFolder%\

ECHO Uninstalling Rational Products

%ratinalDestFolder%\rationaluninstalltool.exe %logFile% -c
```

Any idea why the script which was added to the startup is being removed while the first script is being executed.

Comment: If you simplify the first script, would the second script entry in the registry disappear? In other word, what line from the first script seems to cause the removal of the second script?

Comment: There is no line that cause the removal of the second script, i've `timeout` at the end of this script and i saw that this script has benn added, but after the reboot it hasn't started.